# Android Japanese Fonts

Tags: android, fonts

I would like to find a different font than the standard one provided with Android for a Japanese app. I haven't been able to find any good information on it yet. My question is, are there alternative Japanese fonts available for the Android, which can be distributed with an app, and do not require rooting of the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any application can bundle a font within it for use within that app. Many `TrueType` fonts will work just fine. You will need to associate that font with each `TextView` (and widget inheriting from `TextView`, like `EditText`) via `setTypeface()` in Java. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler) illustrating this.

If, OTOH, you are trying to replace the *system* font, and affect all applications, that is at best achieved by rooting the phone, and it may require a full firmware replacement.